# scan networks while in AP mode (network manager)

Tags: linux, network-programming, dbus, networkmanager

Using Network Manager, is it possible to scan for networks while the wifi device is in AP mode ? I know that one can do 'iw dev wlan0 scan ap-force' and parse the output, but is there a D-Bus API solution ?

For context, I'm building an embedded device (think Amazon Echo) that communicates with a mobile app in AP mode to scan for and choose an SSID to connect to. Thus, I need the device to be a hotspot and scan at the same time.